# Append dataframe in nested loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have two dataframes dfnew and dfrest and using them in nested loop as below, And a new dataframe `Newtempdf = pd.DataFrame()`.

I want to collect all entries of z when m> 70 in Newtempdf

also, how I can join i in better way?

```
for x, y in dfnew.iterrows():
    dfrestnew = dfrest[dfrest['zip'].isin([y[4],'Blank'])]
    i = str(y['companyName'])+' '+str(y['address'])+' '+str(y['city'])+' '+str(y['state'])+' '+str(y['zip'])
    i = i.lower()
    for x1, z in dfrestnew.iterrows():
        m = 0
        j = str(z['companyName'])+' '+str(z['address'])+' '+str(z['city'])+' '+str(z['state'])+' '+str(z['zip'])
        j = j.lower()
        score = fuzz.ratio(i, j)
        if score>=m:
            m = score
        if m> 70:
            # How to append in Newtempdf??
```

Sample df (`(sep=',')` for easier formatting):

```
companyName,address,city,state,zip,country
Austin Cake Studio,1504 Chisholm Trl,Round Rock,TX,78681,US
Magee's Bakery,8188 Orangeburg Rd,Maysville,KY,41056,US
Sweet Shoppe,1200 Kay Dr, Olney,TX,76374,US
```

Comment: Please provide samples of `dfnew`, `dfrest` and the expected `dfrestnew`.

Comment: Sample df:
companyName address city state zip country
....and few entries in them... new to stakoverflow don't know how to add table data.. if I add it's become messy.
dfnew and dfrestnew have same columns but different values... dfrestnew no column no values.

Comment: Better. Now it is not very clear what `dfrestnew = dfrest[dfrest['zip'].isin([y[4],'Blank'])]` is supposed to do. Then what is `m` ? could you develop a bit?

Comment: dfrestnew is a dataframe created by filtered value of dfrest where zip code is same as dfnew 'y' entry plus where zip code is blank. 'm' is variable which  is equivalent to max fuzzy score.

I want to collect all entries of z when m> 70 in Newtempdf